# Postgresql Provided user name and authenticated user name do not match

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to get tinyRSS running on my own server using PostgreSql. However I keep getting this error:

```
LOG:  provided user name (tinyrss) and authenticated user name (apache) do not match
FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "tinyrss"
```

I understand that postgresql uses host based authentication and since I do not have the same account name(tinyrss) as the host machine I needed to use a username map so I added this line into `pg_ident.conf`:

```
# MAPNAME       SYSTEM-USERNAME         PG-USERNAME
tinyrss hongyi tinyrss
```

and under `pg_hba.conf`:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
# local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident map=tinyrss
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
```

Can I know what I am doing wrong and the solution to this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Replace the `ident` with `trust` in `pg_hba.conf` and try again

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using `ident` authentication and connecting with a user that has the operating system account name of `apache`, you need to have an entry mapping `tinyrss` to `apache`, as the message is hinting at.

The following line should work for you in your `pg_ident.conf`:

`tinyrss apache tinyrss`

Answer (score 1):

I'm leaving my hint here since this question got high in google at the time I was searching for an answer.

If you are using ssl authentication make sure your ~/.postgresql/postgresql.crt common name is the same as the user you are trying to connect as. This user must be defined in pg_hba.conf on the server you are trying to connect to. Also your client must be connecting from allowed IP/host.

Hope this helps someone.